# How to specify command line arguments for my C program when running it from the Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I have some code that is executed from the command line. It takes 3 parameters:

```
"example.txt" 3 s
```

I want to be able to run this program from inside of my Eclipse IDE instead of running it from the command line but I do not know how to assign the parameters without creating bugs int the program.

Here is the main method below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <input file> <num clusters> "
            "<linkage type>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
} else {
    item_t *items = NULL;
    int num_items = process_input(&items, argv[1]);
    set_linkage(argv[3][0]);
    if (num_items) {
        cluster_t *cluster = agglomerate(num_items, items);
        free(items);

        if (cluster) {
            fprintf(stdout, "CLUSTER HIERARCHY\n"
                    "--------------------\n");
            print_cluster(cluster);

            int k = atoi(argv[2]);
            fprintf(stdout, "\n\n%d CLUSTERS\n"
                    "--------------------\n", k);
            get_k_clusters(cluster, k);
            free_cluster(cluster);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I am using c++ and eclipse IDE.

Comment: If you tell us which IDE you use, then maybe you'll get an answer.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: BTW why is this tagged C++ ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the command-line arguments inside the IDE, so you just run the program from within the IDE? Depending on the IDE it's either in the project settings or in some "Run" settings. ALso remember that the programs working directory might not be what you expect, so don't use relative paths for files or directories.

Comment: Yes i would like to input the arguments inside of the eclipse ide instead of running the program from command-line.

Comment: Tags C and C++; title with C; question: _I am using C++_... (Looks like plain C to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to create a debug/run configuration for said project. Go to Run->Debug Configurations, select C/C++ Application, then create a new configuration. After that, you have to specify some information, like the application, the eclipse project, and your program`s **arguments**, on the Arguments Tab.

Screenshots from [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.debug.application.doc%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_o_run_config.htm) are a bit old, but should give you the idea.

After that, hit Debug or Run, and Eclipse shoud start your program with the given parameters.